# What is the use of the path /usr/share/pyshared in python?

Tags: python, linux, path

I found that some applications developed with python drop their files in this path, what is the use of this path, and what files should I put in it ?

Answer (score 2):

That directory includes architecture-independent python modules that can be shared by multiple python version. Do not manipulate that directory.

See [Debian Python Policy Chapter 1 - Python Packaging](http://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/python-policy/ch-python.html)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Debian python policy](http://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/python-policy/ch-python.html#s-paths).

> 1.5 Module Path
>
> By default, Python modules are searched in the directories listed in
>   the PYTHONPATH environment variable and in the sys.path Python
>   variable. Since python2.4 version 2.4.5-3, python2.5 version 2.5.2-7,
>   python2.6 version 2.6.2-1, and in all python2.7 versions, sys.path
>   does not include a /usr/lib/pythonXY.zip entry anymore. Directories
>   with private Python modules must be absent from the sys.path. Public
>   Python modules not handled by python-central or python-support must be
>   installed in the system Python modules directory,
>   /usr/lib/pythonX.Y/dist-packages for python2.6 and later, and
>   /usr/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages for python2.5 and earlier. Public
>   Python 3 modules must be installed in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages.
>   Modules managed by python-support are installed in another directory
>   which is added to the sys.path using the .pth mechanism. The .pth
>   mechanism is documented in the Python documentation of the site
>   module. A special directory is dedicated to public Python modules
>   installed by the local administrator, /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
>   for all python3 versions, /usr/local/lib/python2.Y/dist-packages for
>   python2.6 and later, and /usr/local/lib/python2.Y/site-packages for
>   python2.5 and earlier. For a local installation by the administrator
>   of python2.6 and later, a special directory is reserved to Python
>   modules which should only be available to this Python,
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.Y/site-packages (and
>   /usr/local/lib/python3/site-packages for all python3 versions).
>   Unfortunately, for python2.5 and earlier this directory is also
>   visible to the system Python. Additional information on appending
>   site-specific paths to the module search path is available in the
>   official documentation of the site module.
>
> When binary packages ship identical source code for multiple Python
>   versions, for instance /usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/foo.py and
>   /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/foo.py, these should point to a
>   common file. Version specific directories for identical source code
>   are not required for python3 and must not be used for this. A common
>   location to share, across Python versions, arch-independent files
>   which would otherwise go to the directory of system public modules is
>   /usr/share/pyshared. For python3, a special location is not required,
>   use /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
>
> 1.6 Hooks for updates to installed runtimes
>
> The python binary package has special hooks to allow other packages to
>   act upon updates to the installed runtimes. This mechanism is required
>   to handle changes of the default Python runtime in some packages and
>   to enable the Python packaging helpers. There are three supported hook
>   types which come in the form of scripts which are invoked from the
>   maintainer scripts of the Python runtime packages when specific
>   installations, removals, or upgrades occur.
>
> /usr/share/python/runtime.d/*.rtinstall: these are called when a
>   runtime is installed or becomes supported. The first argument is
>   "rtinstall", the second argument is the affected runtime (for example
>   pythonX.Y) and the third and fourth argument are the old and new
>   version of this packaged runtime if this runtime was already installed
>   but unsupported.
>
> /usr/share/python/runtime.d/*.rtremove: these are called when a
>   runtime is removed or stops being supported. The first argument is
>   "rtremove", and the second argument is the affected runtime (for
>   example pythonX.Y).
>
> /usr/share/python/runtime.d/*.rtupdate: these are called when the
>   default runtime changes. The first argument is either "pre-rtupdate",
>   called before changing the default runtime, or "rtupdate", called when
>   changing the default runtime, or "post-rtupdate", called immediately
>   afterwards. The second argument is the old default runtime (for
>   example pythonX.Y), and the third argument is the new default runtime
>   (for example pythonX.Z).